# Different update trigger for binding and validation

Tags: wpf, binding

I need to bind with UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, but in the same time i need to enforce validation rules on every value change. Any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different Dependency Property for the real data, and add LostFocus event to the control to update the real data.